# How to css 3rd li in hierarchy?

Tags: php, html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm pretty sure I'm not getting the hierarchy in css for building this. I can't seem to find a place that will actually explain it to me, and how each level works. I've found some that show, but when you build it if you don't know, at least for me, it's kind of hard to see. Never really used css suprisingly until now. If someone wouldn't mind pointing out my error and explaining it please. :)

I'm just trying to add a 2nd drop down (a drop down to my drop down) that will show up horizontally under the initial hidden drop down, when selecting the correct one so the correct php id will populate in the link. I included the PHP just so if I put it in wrong someone could point that out to me as well.

also to add: the 2nd level hidden drop down links seem to be there when I hover over "project" instead of when hovering over the populated projects like it should. The weird thing is the links don't actually show up (not visible), but if i put my mouse there ie lets me know theres a link.

http://jsfiddle.net/HHwLH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css

```
#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

your sub menu and sub sub menu is affected by this.
When you hover on the `li` all `ul` descendants will be affected (submenu and subsubmenu)
in your markup the `ul`s are children of the `li` so you can use the children selector instead of the descendant selector to only show the direct child menu/ul.

```
#navbar li:hover > ul, #navbar li.hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This will work for both submenu and subsubmenu

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HHwLH/2/)

Comment: Got it except one last thing. The last line in fiddle in css, #navbar ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #357;
}, it's not showing a hover color at all.

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr The second to last rule actually sets the colour to black and have a greater specificity than than the next rule so it wont cascade, just remove it. http://jsfiddle.net/HHwLH/4/

Comment: What if I want it to be a different color from the one above it though?

Comment: Then create a rule that specifically targets the lower levels and apply the colour.

Comment: That's what I don't understand how to do I guess though. I put 
    #navbar li:hover ul li:hover ul li a, #navbar li.hover ul li.hover ul li a {
    color: khaki;
}   but it's a no go. I guess I have my structure wrong?

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr the last rule set the colour for the lowest level, just change it to khaki http://jsfiddle.net/HHwLH/5/

Comment: I wanted to be able to change the regular color and the hover color of the last row though. I have the regular colors changed, just no hover on the last drop down.